# Not all Ajax content loading on one domain

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, cross-domain

I have the domain http://whatthecatdragged.in/ forwarded (cloaked) to http://moppy.co.uk/wtcdi/

The root page (index.html) uses [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to load the content. At the original host (moppy.co.uk/wtcdi) the page and all content loads. However, at the domain forwarded domain (whatthecatdragged.in), some of the content does not load. Has it something to do with the way `.each` is used to fire off Ajax calls, as mentioned by [AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2021190/)?

I've attempted to debug this, but peculiarly turning on the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29) console in Firefox 3.5 actually seems to make all the content load.

```
// Content building code:
$(function() {
  // Set a few variables (no need for secrecy with Flickr API key).
  var apiKey = 'myapikey';
  // var tags = '';
  var tagsArr = new Array();
  // Get the photos of flickr user WhatTheCatDraggedIn.
  // This Ajax call always seems to complete.
  $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=' +
    apiKey +
    '&user_id=46206266@N05&extras=date_taken,tags&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    function(data) {

      // Set some variables to ensure alldata is fecthed from second API
      // call (below)  before building majority of content.
      var totalExpected = data.photos.total;
      var totalFetched = 0;
      var photohtml = '';

      // For each photo, do the following:
      $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, item) {
        // Set size of photo thumbnail to display.
        var size = 's';
        var append = '';
        if (i == 0) {
          // Display most recent thumbnail larger, and add a line
          // break for small pics beneath it.
          size = 'm';
          append = '<br />'
        }
        //Only display thmbnails of 4 most recent catches (1 large, 3 small).
        if (i <= 3) {
          var photoSrc =
            'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
            item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_' +
            size + '.jpg'
          //Each thumbnail links to that photo's Flickr page.
          var flickrPage =
            'http://flickr.com/photos/' + item.owner +
            '/' + item.id + '/';
          // Each thumbnail has a big tooltip, with tags formatted appropriately.
          var formattedTags = item.tags.replace(/\s/g, "<br />");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/cat/, "cat: ");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/loc/, "location: ");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/victim/, "victim: ");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/status/, "status: ");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/floor/, " floor");
          formattedTags = formattedTags.replace(/toy/, " toy");
          //Append the built html to one varable for adding to page shortly
          photohtml +=
            '<a class="flickr-page-link" href="' +
            flickrPage + '"><img src = "' +
            photoSrc + '" title="' + formattedTags + '"/>' +
            append + '</a>';
        }

        var photoID = item.id;
        // Get the detailed photo information (including tags) for the photo.
        // This is the call that perhaps fails or at least content
        // generated after this call does not load.
        $.getJSON(
          'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=' +
          apiKey + '&photo_id=' + photoID +
          '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
          function(data) {
            if (data.photo.tags.tag != '') {
              $.each(data.photo.tags.tag, function(j, item) {
                // Place all tags in an aray for easier handling.
                tagsArr.push(item.raw);
              });
              // Incrememt number of photos fetched.
              totalFetched += 1;
              // Have we got them all?
              if (totalFetched == totalExpected)
                fetchComplete();
            }
          });
        // Builds a shedload more content once all JSON calls are completed.
        function fetchComplete() {
          // ### BUILD VICTIM list ###
          // format a regex to match tags beginnign : "victim: "
          var vicRe = /^v[a-z]+:\s([a-z\s]+)/
          // Match the regex to the tags and count number of matches per tag.
          var vicCounts = tagsArr.countVals(vicRe);
          var victimsHtml = "";

          // For each victim.
          for (var i in vicCounts) {
            var strippedTag = [i].toString().replace(/\W/g, "");
            console.debug(strippedTag);
            // Add a line of html with the type of victim and the number of victims of that type
            victimsHtml +=
              "<a href='http://flickr.com/photos/46206266@N05/tags/victim" +
              strippedTag + "/'>" + [i] +
              " (" + vicCounts[i] + ") </a><br />";
          };
          // Replace existing HTML with new version.
          $('#types-dragged').html(victimsHtml);

          // ### BUILD STATUS PIE CHART ###
          // Build a theme for chart colours.
          var wtcdicharttheme = {
            colors: ['#C66800', '#D3C70B', '#DD3D0B', '#D30729',
              '#DDA70B'
            ],
            marker_color: '#000000',
            font_color: '#000000',
            background_colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff']
          };

          // Create a new chart object, include css id of canvas
          // where chart will be drawn.
          var g = new Bluff.Pie('status', '275x250');
          // Set a theme and stuff.
          g.set_theme(wtcdicharttheme);
          // No title, as this exists via the raw page HTML.
          g.title = '';
          g.legend_font_size = "50px";
          g.marker_font_size = "20px";

          // Build a regex string to match tags beginning "status: ".
          var statRe = /^s[a-z]+:\s([a-z\s]+)/
          // Match regex to tags and return an object with tag
          // names and number of occurences.
          var statCounts = tagsArr.countVals(statRe);

          // For each status.
          for (var i in statCounts) {
            // Add data to the chart
            g.data([i], [statCounts[i]]);
          };
          // Draw the chart.
          g.draw();

          // ### BUILD LOCATION LIST ###
          // Build a regex that matches tags beginning "loc: "
          var locRe = /^l[a-z]+:\s([a-z\s]+)/
          // Match regex to tags and return an object with
          // tag names and number of occurences.
          var locCounts = tagsArr.countVals(locRe);
          var locatHtml = "";

          // For each location.
          for (var i in locCounts) {
            var strippedTag = [i].toString().replace(/\W/g, "");
            // Add a line of html with the location and the
            //number of times victims found in that location.
            locatHtml +=
              "<a href='http://flickr.com/photos/46206266@N05/tags/loc" +
              strippedTag + "/'>" + [i] + " (" +
              locCounts[i] + ") <br />";
          };
          // Replace existing html with newly built information.
          $('#locations').html(locatHtml);

          // ### BUILD CAT LIST ###
          // Build a regex that maches tags beginning "cat: ".
          var catRe = /^c[a-z]+:\s([a-z_\s]+)/
          //Match regex to find number of catches each cat has made
          var catCounts = tagsArr.countVals(catRe);

          // For each cat.
          for (var i in catCounts) {
            var strippedTag = [i].toString().replace(/\W/g, "");
            // Insert number of catches to div titled "(catname)-catch"
            $('#' + [i] + '-catch').html(
              "<a href='http://flickr.com/photos/46206266@N05/tags/" +
              strippedTag + "/'>" + catCounts[i] + "</a>");
          };
        }
      });
      // Insert total dragged onto page.
      $('#total-dragged').html(data.photos.total);
      // Insert photos onto page.
      $('#latest-catches').html(photohtml);
      // Add tooltips to the images from Flickr.
      $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
          style: {
            name: 'wtcdin'
          },
          position: {
            target: 'mouse',
            adjust: {
              x: 8,
              y: 10
            }
          }
        })
      });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1:** I contacted the domain name company, their advice was basically "don't use [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)". Still can't see why it would work under one domain name and not another... Could it be to do with the fact that they "forward" the domain by means of a frame?

Comment: I followed both links and 'Types of items dragged in', 'Locations items discovered' and 'Status of items' don't load in either case...

Comment: Yes, it seems I had previously, within the same session had firebug enabled on the tab I was viewing the version at moppy.co.uk. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will block AJAX requests that are sent outside of the domain that the script is hosted on. This is most likely the cause of your problem from the sound of things.

EDIT: I've found the problem, you have console.debug() calls in your script. This method is defined by the Firebug Console which is why it's only working while the Console is active. Try removing any calls to console.debug() and see how it goes.

Comment: I followed the link and check the source, and what he means when he says forwarding is that he's using frames. Since the content of the frame - including the `<script>` element - comes from the appropriate domain there's no cross-domain problem.

Comment: Hm I hadn't considered I was using frames... that seems to be just the way the hosting company have implemented the forwarding... I've also added the code above and commented each .getJSON call to show which ones are definielty happening and which may not be...